# Scala slf4j logging issue when given multiple (>2) params

Tags: scala, logging, slf4j

```
val LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getSimpleName)
LOG.info("This log works {} {} ", 1, 2)
LOG.info("This log fails {} {} {} ", 1, 2, 3)
```

**Compilation error:**
overloaded method value info with alternatives: (x$1: org.slf4j.Marker,x$2: String,x$3: Object*)Unit  (x$1: org.slf4j.Marker,x$2: String,x$3: Any,x$4: Any)Unit  (x$1: String,x$2: Object*)Unit cannot be applied to (String, Int, Int, Int)

I'm using slf4j-log4j12 + slf4j-api for logging.

Answer (score 3):

The boxing conversion of the Int to Object is not done implicitly.

You can force `(42: Integer)` explicitly.

Also, calls to `getSimpleName` are dangerous in Scala because Scala encodes class names in a way that can throw an exception. This is a known issue, and affects classes that are not top-level; it's safer to just avoid it.

Comment: Also, aren't there Scala logging layers to avoid the Java API.

Comment: even LOG.info("This log fails {} {} {} ", 1:Int, 2:Int, (3:Int)) doesn't work.

Comment: Or LOG.info("This log fails {} {} {} ", 1, 2, (3:Any)) for that matter

Comment: `1` is already an `Int` and `Any`, but not an `Integer`, which is the boxed representation required to conform to `Object`. It's not willing to go from `Int` to `Object`. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8661